# ASP.net JQuery Function w/ Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am working on a project with Razor Pages and I am trying to create a cascading drop down list. I have got as far as to make the list and return it. I have followed a couple of tutorials but I cannot figure out how to call the C# function correctly.f Here is what I have:

```
    <section class="bg-light pt-7 pb-7 pt-md-0 pb-md-8">
        <div class="container position-relative px-md-0">
            <div class="search-box search-box-dark">

                <form method="GET" action="listings-half-screen-map-list.html">

                    @* This will be the first drop down *@
                    <div class="select-default">
                        <select id="scaleID" class="select-location" asp-for="scaleId" asp-items="Model.scl"><option>Choose Scale</option></select>
                    </div>
                    @* This will be the second drop down *@
                    <div class="select-default">
                        <select id="manfID" class="select-location" asp-for="manfId" asp-items="Model.man"><option>Choose Manufacturer</option></select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="select-default">
                        <select id="vechID" class="select-location" asp-items="ViewBag.Vehicles"><option>Choose Vehicle</option></select>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Search </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <script>
    $("#manfID").change(function () {
        var manF = $("#manfID").val();
        var url = "/Pages/Index";

        $.getJSON(url, { scaleId: manF }, function (data) {  
            var item = "";
            $("#vechID").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                item += '<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.text + '</option>'
            });
            $("#vechID").html(item);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Then this is my C# Code:

```
    public JsonResult OnGetSubCategories(int scaleId)
    {
        List<Vehicle> list = new List<Vehicle>();

        list = _context.Vehicles.Where(a => a.ScaleId == scaleId && a.ManufacturerId == manfId).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(list);
    }
```

Both are within the Index.html and index.htmlcs file's.  Any advice would be appreciate, I think the URL is the part that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you have to pass the path of the Razor Page + the name of the method. Like:

```
var url = '/Pages/Index/OnGetSubCategories';
```

or

```
 var url = '/Index/OnGetSubCategories';
```

Comment: RazorPages do not have controllers..It has code behind the html. So my theory is it should still be the Index/functionName. even tried /functionname with no luck.

Comment: When I do either of those I get a 404.. So dont think that is the right way..

Answer (score 0):

To pass a URL with Ajax with Razor Pages use the following command:

```
   var url2 = '@Url.Page("index","SubCategories")';
```

Note that we do NOT need the "OnGet"  the rest will be handled by the compiler.